# Alsa tempo vs. PPQ

Tags: midi, alsa

Recently I've been playing with the haskell ALSA interface, and I had to notice, that I do not really understand the concepts of tempo and PPQ.

Earlier I've written a Swig-Python interface to ALSA and in there I find the following piece of code (probably copied from somewhere else):

```
1    void  AlsaMidiIfc::setTempo (int bpm) {
2       int queue = this->getOutQueue();
3       snd_seq_queue_tempo_t *tempo;
4       snd_seq_queue_tempo_alloca (&tempo);
5       snd_seq_queue_tempo_set_tempo(tempo, 60 * 1000000 / bpm);
6       snd_seq_queue_tempo_set_ppq(tempo, PPQ);
7       snd_seq_set_queue_tempo (mySeq, queue, tempo);
8    }
```

When I put an event into a queue, the time is always specified in ticks, right? So the only timing question to answer is "how long is a tick?".

- What is the point of specifying *two* values, i.e. tempo and PPQ?
- What would be the effect of changing the tempo, but leaving PPQ as it
  is?
- If I don't set PPQ at all, but only the tempo, what would be the
  result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Standard MIDI Files use these two values (tempo and PPQ) to specify the tempo.
  The ALSA sequencer just uses the same mechanism.
- The tempo value is the number of microseconds per quarter note.
  Increasing it will increase the length of a tick, i.e., make playback slower.
- A PPQ value of zero would be invalid.

Comment: Does this mean one tick is tempo/ppq useconds long?